# Read once file handle

Tags: ruby, file

I have a situation where I'd like to return a file handle from a routine. When the last byte of that file handle is read, the file being read is deleted. This will be a simple way to create a temporary file that is deleted once it's been read.

[Tempfile](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) doesn't really work for this purpose. To use Tempfile I would have to create the Tempfile, read and write in the entire contents of the source file to the Tempfile, rewind the Tempfile, then return the Tempfile object. Very wasteful. I just want to open a file and return a file handle, but one which deletes the file when the last byte is read.

I could probably write this class myself, but I'd rather use an existing solution if it exists.

Comment: Do you mean something like the use of an [ensure clause](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/weird-ruby-2-rescue-interrupt-ensure/), such as `def m; f = File.open(fname, mode);...; x = meth1(f); ..., y = meth2(f);...; begin; ensure; f.close; unlink(fname), end; end`?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to return a file handle type or can it be something that works on a file handle? If its the latter then you could use a closure and a lambda. Something like below:

```
def sp_handle(fname)
  handle = File.open(fname)

  ->(){
    line = handle.gets
    line ? line : (File.unlink(fname); handle.close)
  }

end
```

Comment: It's always best to close a file before--not after--deleting it.

Comment: I guess I could return nil at the end of that sequence(handle.close;File.unlink(fname); nil)

Comment: Check the sequence in your answer. My previous comment was made [tongue in cheek](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tongue-in-cheek).